# Acts As Taggable On with Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, acts-as-taggable-on

I have installed the gem acts-as-taggable-on, everything is working well with my model, but I would like to use Rails Admin and this is where I have a problem...
In the form new or edit, I would like to display the field Tags with 2 columns, the first one with the list of all the tags already recorded and the second with tags I want to use. For now, I just have a simple field, where I can enter tags with comma.

I have added the code below in rails_admin.rb:

```
config.model Recipe do  
 edit do
    field :title
    field :url
    field :prep_time
    field :cook_time
    field :serve
    field :picture
    field :publisher
    field :ingredient_lines
    field :ingredients
    field :tag_list do
      html_attributes do
        {:style => "width:90%"}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Just to give you a idea of what I want, here are a screenshot.
[Screenchot link](http://s9.postimg.org/kiyy0xe1b/Recipe_Popnfood_App_V2_Admin.png)
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You have used a wrong Tag, `activeadmin` is not `Rails Admin`

Comment: You right, I have used the wrong tag ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I have created my own tag model, no everything is working well.